# Python DeferredList callback reporting success when deferreds raise error

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I have the following simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet import defer             
from twisted.web.client import getPage, reactor

def success(results):
  print 'success'              

def error(results):
  print 'error'         

def finished(results):
  print 'finished', results

tasks = []

d = getPage('thiswontwork').addCallback(success).addErrback(error)
tasks.append(d)

dl = defer.DeferredList(tasks)
dl.addCallback(finished)

reactor.run()
```

That produces the following output:

```
error
finished [(True, None)]
```

I would expect this error task to return a false since the getPages task fails and calls it's error callback. Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me add a thought beyond what you selected as the answer:

In your question you print the parameter that your deferred(list) callback(`finished`) is called with, and you're noting that you would expect it to be `false` (because of the error happening prior)

That expectation suggests your thinking about deferreds in a way thats going to confuse you [later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450952/how-to-catch-unhandled-error-in-deferred-originating-from-reactor-stop).

Let me see if I can break this apart...

(There are a lot of details and subtly in this stuff, I'm going to try my best)

A deferred is:

1. a queue of function callbacks
2. Which, for each 'step' in the queue there is both a `callback` and and `errback` function callback stored

   - `addCallbacks` (note its plural) lets you add both the callback and the errback at once
   - `addCallback` adds a callback (and sets the errback to skip to the next entry in the queue)
   - `addErrback` adds a errback (and sets the callback to skip to the next entry in the queue)
   - `addBoth` add a function as both the errback and the callback (... which means it needs to figure out why its being called via the arg its called with

Drawing from [krondo's part 7](http://krondo.com/?p=1682): (...Twisted docs also have a [good drawing](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#auto3))

[image: Krondo's deferred drawing]

If a function is added to a deferred as a `callback` and the deferred has reached the point in its 'firing' that the step before this one return successfully, the deferred with pass the return value of the previous successfully function to the function defined in the `callback`.

If a function is added to a deferred as a `errback` and the deferred has reached the point in its 'firing' where the previous step returned a `Failure` object (or raised an exception, which twisted transforms into a `Failure` object), then the `errback` will be called with that `Failure` object.   ***Note!*** if the errback doesn't return a `Failure`, the deferred will flip back to calling the `callback` chain, not the errback!

Drawing from [Krondo's part 9](http://krondo.com/?p=1825):

[image: Connections between callbacks and errorbacks]

While this all may seem like a bit of a brain-twister, it lets you implement things like error-recovery mid-deferred, which can be really helpful (and not all that uncommon in protocol design)

I.E: (Drawing from [Krondo's part 9](http://krondo.com/?p=1825)):

[image: krondo's drawing of a deferred recovering from an error]

To put this all together, the error in your thought of "I would expect this error task to return a false" is that `finished` isn't called by any sort of error task, its called by the deferred, and on top of that *It's only called on success* (because its only loaded into the deferred as a `callback` not as an `errback`)

If you had loaded the `finished` function as both an `errback` and a `callback` (perhaps via `addBoth`), and you had followed the answers advice to forward the return-state of the errback via returning the `Failure` object, your `finished` function *still technically wouldn't be passed* `False`! it would receive a `Failure` object.

... Like I said, lots of subtly in this stuff ...

If you find any of this helpful (... or even if you don't - I'm not as good of a writer), you really should dig through [Krondo's twisted introduction](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327).  I think you'll find a lot of this snaps into focus after going through that guide.

Comment: Thanks Mike I really appreciate this depth answer, it makes a lot more sense now I was definitely thinking about deferreds in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't return the error/exception from your `errback`, then that error is considered to be handled. Try changing your `error()` function:

```
def error(results):
    print 'error'
    return results
```

This way the error (`results`) is returned, and then the `DeferredList` will see the error and call its `errback` as well.

Comment: That makes sense, i assumed that if it went through the error callback it would know that an error had occurred. Thank you!